# Why does hvc make Undefined instruction exception?

Tags: assembly, armv7, bare-metal

I'm writing a program with the ARMv7-A assembly language.
I want to use Virtualization Extension and make the processor mode PL2 in the non secure world.

> Therefore, I use `hvc` instruction as follow:
>
> 1. start in secure PL1(SVC) mode.
> 2. set MVBAR and VBAR.
> 3. use `smc` instruction and go to monitor mode.
> 4. In the monitor mode, set SCR.NS bit ,set HVBAR and excetpion return.
> 5. make the processor mode SVC.
> 6. call hvc

**the code**

```
    .text

    .section .eitbra , "ax"
    // non-secure vector table
    .org    0x00000000
    b   startup_entry       // 00 : reset
    b   default_entry       // 04 : undefined instruction exception
    b   default_entry       // 08 : supervisor call (SVC)
    b   default_entry       // 0C : prefetch abort
    b   default_entry       // 10 : data abort
    nop                     // 14 : (reserved)
    b   default_entry       // 18 : interrupt
    b   default_entry       // 1C : fast interrupt
    .org    0x00000020
    // secure vector table
secure_vector:
    b   startup_entry       // 00 : reset
    b   default_entry       // 04 : undefined instruction exception
    b   default_entry       // 08 : supurvisor call (SVC)
    b   default_entry       // 0C : prefetch abort
    b   default_entry       // 10 : data abort
    nop                     // 14 : (reserved)
    b   default_entry       // 18 : interrupt
    b   default_entry       // 1C : fast interrupt
    .org    0x00000040
hyper_vector:
    // hyper vector table
    nop                     // 00 : reset
    b   default_entry       // 04 : undefined instruction exception
    b   default_entry       // 08 : hyper call from hyper mode
    b   default_entry       // 0C : prefetch abort
    b   default_entry       // 10 : data abort
    b   hyper_entry         // 14 : hyper call from non-secure world (HVC)
    b   default_entry       // 18 : interrupt
    b   default_entry       // 1C : fast interrupt
    .org    0x00000060
monitor_vector:
    // monitor vector table
    nop                     // 00 : (reserved)
    nop                     // 04 : (reserved)
    b   hyper_init          // 08 : monitor call
    b   default_entry       // 0C : prefetch abort
    b   default_entry       // 10 : data abort
    nop                     // 14 : (reserved)
    b   default_entry       // 18 : interrupt
    b   default_entry       // 1C : fast interrupt
    .org    0x00000080

startup_entry:
    // set cpsr
    mov r0, #(PSM_SVC | CPSR_I | CPSR_F)
    msr cpsr, r0

    // set vector base address
    ldr r1, =secure_vector
    mcr p15, 0, r1, c12, c0, 0  // VBAR
    ldr r1, =monitor_vector
    mcr p15, 0, r1, c12, c0, 1  // MVBAR

    // move to monitor mode and restart as non-secure world
    smc #0

  nonsecure_init:
    ldr r1, =_start
    mcr p15, 0, r1, c12, c0, 0  // VBAR
    // set cpsr
    mrs r0, cpsr
    mov r0, #(PSM_SVC | CPSR_I | CPSR_F)
    msr cpsr, r0

    // hyper call test
    hvc #0

    b default_entry


hyper_init:
    mrc p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 0   //read scr
    orr r0, r0, #1  // set NS bit
    mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 0   //set scr
    mrs r0, cpsr

    ldr r0, =hyper_vector
    mcr p15, 4, r0, c12, c0, 0  // HVBAR
    movs pc, lr

hyper_entry:
    ldr sp, =_stack_start+0x50
    eret
default_entry:
    nop
    mrs r0, cpsr
    nop
    wfi
    b default_entry
```

But, at the hvc instruction, undefined instruction exception occured.
This code was called from U-Boot console(`go` command) on TWR-LS1021A board(Cortex-A7).

Anyone know what causes this/how to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this myself.
I didn't set `SCR.HCE` bit.
If this bit is not set, `hvc` instruction is undefined even if in non-secure PL1 mode.
After setting this bit, hyper exception occured.